# executing command prompt command in MySql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have one table called table1 in that there are two fields, let say field1 and field2.

table Structure

```
Table:table1 
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| field1 | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| field2 | int(50)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

What i am trying to do is that, when there are records inserted into table1, the values of field1 and field2 get stored in one text file which on c drive called abc.txt.

I want to do it by calling command prompt command which is called inside the table1's After insert trigger called triger1.

I have done it in sql server but i need it using mysql:

here is sql server trigger

```
create trigger [dbo].[trigger1] on [dbo].[table1] 
for insert

As 

Declare @field_1 varchar(50),@field_2 int,@cmd varchar(250);

select @field_1=i.field1 from inserted i;
select @field_2=i.field2 from inserted i;


PRINT @field_1
Print @field_2;

SET @cmd= 'echo ' + @field_1+','+cast(@field_2 as varchar)+ '>C:\abc.txt'
EXEC Master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

And mysql trigger that i have written

```
DELIMITER $$
```

CREATE TRIGGER tri1
   AFTER UPDATE ON table1
     FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN

```
Declare Field_1 varchar(50);
Declare Field_2 int(50);

Set Field_1 = NEW.Field1;
Set Field_2 = NEW.Field2;

System echo concat(Field_1,Field_2) > abc.txt;                

   END;
 $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

after executing this command it gives an error as

```
    -> $$
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'echo
    concat(Field_1,Field_2) > abc.txt;

    END' at line 12
```

I am new to mysql, may be I am doing it wrong.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Approach this from a different angle. Let MySQL do what it does best and do just the SQL query. Call this from the command prompt and let it return the results back to you and then save it to a file.

Comment: cant we do it using triggers, i need to do it through mysql trigger

Comment: Use the trigger to save the concatenated data into another table then have an external script query the table and save the results to a file?

Comment: @Hayden actually i am new to mysql just have started working with mysql can you please help me , just improve my trigger